# sonar project properties Exclude rule squid:S1191

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have a Java project and it will be submitted in Gitlab. In the code present in Gitlab, SonarQube will be used for its analysis. Currently the project is showing Code Smells with detail `Classes from "sun.*" packages should not be used`.

How do I include the exclusion of this rule when my Maven Project is analysed by SonarQube?

What I go to know is that we have to put this in `sonar-project.properties`. But I am not able to find what tag should be used for that.

Comment: I edited your comment to improve the formatting. The use of `code` formatting is undesirable for non-code words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Maven projects, `pom.xml` is the main configuration file. If we add below lines in that, the rule `S1191` will not be applied. And this is in tight coupling with the project, which is what was required. So, no need to configure any SonarQube instance, rather specify below lines in `pom.xml` under `properties` tag. That will work.

```
<sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>e1</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>
<sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>squid:S1191</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>
<sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>**/*.java</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>
```

Comment: How would that go for a build.gradle?